# Extend fragment container with header line

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity with a fragment container for showing different details of an object in my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">


   <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This works fine. Tabs are displayed properly.

Now I want to add an header line to this actitivy which shows "static" content regardless of the current fragment for the details. The header line shall be on top with the fragment-container below. So I changed the layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

      <LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:id="@+id/LabeledObjectHeaderInfo"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeaderID"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="@string/txtHeaderID"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeaderIDValue"
           android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="20sp" />      

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeaderName"
           android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight=".20"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="@string/txtHeaderName"
            android:textSize="20sp" />   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHeaderNameValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="test"
            android:textSize="20sp" />           


   </LinearLayout >    

   <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
          >
   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is now, that only the header is shown, but not the content of the fragments. I only changed the layout file up to now (as you can see by the "test"-texts), but no other code.

What am I doing wrong and where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

In your container LinearLayout you have `android:orientation="horizontal"` which shows its first child LinearLayout i.e the Header, but hides its second child LinearLayout i.e the content to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<!-- Inner Layouts -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Change it to `android:orientation="vertical"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center">

<!-- Inner Layouts -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

just make the orientation in your main layout **vertical** and it will work fine.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Because you are making its orientation horizontal, the fragments layout goes to the right.

Comment: You are also right, but twntee was one minute faster, so I accepted his answer, sry :/